# Why the color scheme not change when I re-size my screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap and I was trying the following stuff. I made 3 columns, where each column has 2 paragraphs. Using CSS I defined color scheme for medium-sized-screens , large-sized-screens and extra-small-screens.

Initially the color that I see is orange. That is just the color I expected. But when I re-size the screen from large to extra-small I do not see any color change. I cannot get the reason for it ? What is the mistake that I am making ?

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap.css' />
    <style>
        .col-md-4 {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .col-xs-4 {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .col-lg-4 {
            background-color: orange;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4'>
                <p> You shout it out, But I can't hear a word you say !</p>
                <p> Beqarar karke humein yun na jaiye..Aapko hamari kasam laut aaiye</p>
            </div>

            <div class='col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4'>
                <p> I have started liking David Guetta's work !</p>
                <p> I really liked his song 'Titanium' :-)</p>
            </div>

            <div class='col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4'>
                <p> I am enjoying the saturday afternoon and it is 3:24 by clock.</p>
                <p> How about going for a movie ?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='js/bootstrap.js' />
</body>
```

Comment: `I defined color scheme for medium-sized-screens` No, actually you did that for all sizes of screens. You should use CSS [media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules arent using media queries, they are always added, so the last will always take effect.

If you want to modify their existing styles you should look into using mixins with Bootstrap's less files.

Comment: I have not understood your answer.

Comment: CSS rules have precedence. If they are equally specific, the last one will override any previous rule. Try moving .col-md-4 to the bottom of the style declaration, you'll see the background is always yellow.